# community driven video platform

Tags: video, django, python

I am looking for a platform to build a community-driven education video site. We already have quite a few community web-apps runing on python/django, so something based on these technologies would be easier to integrate with the existing apps. The content will also include recorded courses, so integration with course-capturing tools is a desired feature.

[Kaltura](http://corp.kaltura.com/) seems to provide many of the things I'm looking for, but the Python support seem to be on early stages. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing much in the way of requirements, but have you taken a look at [MediaCore](http://mediacorecommunity.org/)? It's essentially a (Python-based) video-focused CMS with everything already in place to set up a community site. There's also a [hosted version](http://mediacore.com/) with free trial if you want to check it out first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The requirements are vague indeed, but the project is still on the initial investigation phase. We want to explore what frameworks and tools exist before laying out more concrete requirements. MediaCore looks really promising and I will add it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a system that integrates document management, knowledge building and sharing together with a video-community platform, you may consider trying [Plumi](http://www.plumi.org) that's built on top of [Plone](http://www.plone.org).